# Python unittest: write, read, compare does not work

Tags: python, unit-testing, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms

I'm using python unittests and sqlalchemy to test datamodels to store an WTFoms in mariaDB.
The test should create a dataset, write this dataset to db, read this set an compare if original dataset is the same like sored data.

So the partial test looks like that:

```
#set data
myForm = NiceForm()
myForm.name = "Ben"

#write data
db.session.add(myForm)
db.session.commit()

#read data
loadedForms = NiceForm.query.all()

#check that only one entry is in db
self.assertEqual(len(loadedForms), 1)

#compare stores data with dataset
self.assertIn(myForm, loadedForms)
```

The test seams to work fine. No I tried the find out, if the test fails, if dataset != stored data. So ein changed the dataset before compareing it, like this:

```
#set data
myForm = NiceForm()
myForm.name = "Ben"

#write data
db.session.add(myForm)
db.session.commit()

#read data
loadedForms = NiceForm.query.all()

#modify dataset
myForm.name = "Foo"

#show content of both
print(myForm.name)
print(loadedForms[0].name)

#check that only one entry is in db
self.assertEqual(len(loadedForms), 1)

#compare stores data with dataset
self.assertIn(myForm, loadedForms)
```

This test still passed. Why? I output the content of `myForm.name` and `loadedForms[0].name` where both set to `Foo`. This is the reason, why the `self.assertsIn(myForm, loadedForms)`passed the test, but I don't understand:

Why the content of the `loadedForms` is changed, when `Foo`was only applied to `myForm`?

Answer (score 1):

The row identity for MyForm does not change by changing one of the values.

Row numbers have no meaning in a table, but to make the issue clear I will still use them.

Row 153 has 2 fields. Field name = "Ben" and field homeruns = 3.

Now we change the home runs (Ben has hit a home run);

Row 153 has 2 fields. Field name = "Ben" and field homeruns = 4.

It is still row 153, so your `assertIn` wil still return `True`, though one of the values in the row has changed. You only test identity.

If it wouldn't, changing a field in a table row would need to be saved by an `insert` into the table and not an `update` to the row. That is not correct of course; how many Bens do we have? One. And he has 4 home runs, not 3 or 4, depending on which record you look at.